# How to avoid repeating a long subquery in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, repeat

In a postgresql query I have a long subquery (including a lots of sub-subqueries) with several possible outcome ranges and the outcome of the query should be a number which belongs to the specific range.

What I want is to avoid to repeat the long subquery several times.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (result_of_very_long_subquery) BETWEEN 0 AND 3 THEN 1 
WHEN (result_of_very_long_subquery) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 2 
WHEN (result_of_very_long_subquery) BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN 3
WHEN (result_of_very_long_subquery) BETWEEN 11 AND 25 THEN 
ELSE 5 END
```

The solution must be ONE query. (I mean there is no way to create temporary tables, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) - it use a materialized select internally

```
postgres=# WITH x AS (SELECT 10 AS y, pg_sleep(2)) 
              SELECT y FROM x 
              UNION ALL
              SELECT y FROM x 
              UNION ALL 
              SELECT y FROM x 
  y  
────
 10
 10
 10
(3 rows)

Time: 2003.318 ms
```